# Possible Maximum or Minimum??

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was solving some curve sketching questions and wanted to ask something that I am a little confused about.
Why, when we find the first derivative of an equation and set it equal to zero to find the critical points, we refer to the points as "possible" max and min. Are there times when the critical point is not a max or min? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Consider $ y = x ^ 3 $

Comment: Look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1721620/879543

Comment: Consider $y=0$ - its first derivative is zero, but does it suffice to determine that the point is a minimum or maximum...?

Comment: @CiaPan: Unfortunately, depending on how you define 'minimum', or 'maximum', either every point is a minimum or maximum, or every point is neither.

Comment: @Joe You're right, but that was not what I asked about. Does $y' = 0$ suffice to tell minimum from maximum in this case?

Comment: @CiaPan Sorry, I was just making a remark about the confusing terminology. Of course you are correct in saying that you need use other information to determine whether it is a minimum or a maximum. In this case, we can consider how for every neighbourhood of every point $a$, we have $f(x)\geq f(a)$, and $f(x) \leq f(a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The graph of $f(x)=x^2$ has a minimum at $x=0$.
- The graph of $f(x)=-x^2$ has a maximum at $x=0$.
- The graph of $f(x)=x\sin x$ does not have a minimum or maximum at $x=0$. Rather, it has a *local* minimum.
- The graph of $f(x)=x^3$ does not have a minimum, maximum, local minimum, or local maximum at $x=0$. It has a point of inflection.

Just knowing that $f'(x)=0$ at some point is not enough. We need more information. Moreover, not all critical points occur when $f'(x)=0$. The graph of $f(x)=|x|$ is not even differentiable at $x=0$, but it certainly has a minimum there.