# local minima and critical point for a convex function

Tags: convex-optimization

I have learnt that all local extrema occur at critical points, but not all critical points occur at local extrema. That is the rationale where we find critical points when optimization a convex function.

But consider $f(x) = x^2$ with $1\leq x\leq 2$. The minimum of $f(x)$ is 1 at $x=1$. But this local extrema is not a critical point. Is this a counterexample of the above statement?

I think the following statement is true:
When $f$ is convex, a critical point is a global minimum.

Comment: "*all local extrema occur at critical points*" You are missing some conditions here, without which this does not hold true. See for example [Is it correct to say all extrema happen at critical points but not all critical points are extrema?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1721620/is-it-correct-to-say-all-extrema-happen-at-critical-points-but-not-all-critical).