Why is a function not differentiable at the end-points of its domain?
Let $F(x) = x^2$ , where $x\in[0,8]$. Then, $F(x)$ is continuous on $[0,8]$ and $F(x)$ is differentiable on $(0,8)$.
Why can't we say $F(x)$ is differentiable on $[0,8]$?

Welcome to MSE. Please add more details to your question like context(where you found this question or how you came up with it), your attempts for this to be a good quality question.

See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37958/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-for-help-understanding-definitions-and-basic-concepts?cb=1.

what's the definition of differentiable at the endpoints?

It depends on your definition of differentiability. Edit your question to include that definition.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126176/differentiablility-over-closed-intervals

Is there a source telling you that you can't say $x^2$ on $[0,8]$ is differentiable at the endpoints?
The way you pose the question makes me suspect you are studying the Mean Value Theorem, which is about functions continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. Is that the case? When we say a function is differentiable on $(a,b)$, we don't mean it is not differentiable at the endpoints. Nothing is said in the Mean Value Theorem about differentiability at the endpoints because it is irrelevant. Whether or not the function is differentiabile at $a$ and $b$ plays no role.
Example.  Let $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$. This is continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$. The MVT says there is at least one $c$ in $(0,1)$ such that $f'(c) = (f(1)-f(0))/(1-0) = 1$, which means $1/(2\sqrt{c}) = 1$. Such $c$ is $1/4$. We do not need to know anything about differentiability of $f(x)$ at $x = 0$ and $x = 1$. It turns out that at $x = 0$ the function is not differentiabile due to the vertical tangent line, while at $x = 1$ it is differentiabile with derivative $1/2$.

Is this means, function may or may not be differentiable at end points of its domain.

Yes, exactly: when a property is not mentioned that means it does not matter whether it not it is satisfied. If I say a series “converges on $(-1,1)$”, that does not mean it can’t converge at $x= \pm 1$. But if I say its “interval of convergence is $(-1,1)$”, then that does mean the series fails to converge when $x\geq 1$ and $x\leq -1$ because of the meaning of the term “interval of convergence”.

And what about the function F(x)= x^2 in [0,8]. Will it be differentiable at 0 and 8?

How would you define the derivative of a function on $[a,b]$ at an endpoint?

At end points, we can find only left hand derivative or right hand derivative but not both, so we take only one hand derivative and the value of that function at that Point.

Yes, that is the reasonable way to proceed. So you have answered your own question.

But what is the concept of Vertical tangents. How can we know about that?

Just look at the graph of $y = \sqrt{x}$ at $x = 0$: the tangent line there is a vertical line with slope $\infty$, which is consistent with $y' = 1/(2\sqrt{x}) \to \infty$ as $x \to 0^+$.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
